# How username from blocking session id

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query that will login name associated with a block session id if there is a blocking id >0

For instance, when I use the query on this table below:

```
login_name      session_id      blocking_session_id
Billy           50              0
Benjamin        60              70
John            70              0
```

I want the query to output

```
login_name      session_id      
John            70
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: In the example given you can only get "Benjamin 60" for blocking_session_id > 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your question, you want the login names that own blocking sessions.

You can use `exists` for this:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.blocking_session_id = t.session_id)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a single query by joining the same table twice on `t1.session_id = t2.blocking_session_id` (no need for a SELECT inside a SELECT) and selecting the desired fields from `t1`:

> working example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/685824/2

```sql
select t1.login_name, t1.session_id
from mytable as t1
  join mytable as t2
    on t1.session_id = t2.blocking_session_id
```